# Generating Electricity Using a Steam Turbine and Small Motor

Tags: power-generation

I have started a project where I intend to use a Small steam turbine to power small devices in the wilderness. the goal of producing usb standard 5 V and 2 A to 4 A current.

Here is the turbine: http://www.microcosm-engine.com/live-steam-turbine-engine-jti-p-131.html#.WJ_x3FUrJdg

I have seen the engine power a prop in water quite well... and 60 W worth of lights.

The turbine does not have as many specifications listed as I would like.
but it does seem enough for the generation side.

What I am not sure about is what I should use to convert the mechanical energy into electrical.

I think that perhaps a good brushless RC motor with a low kv rating would do the job. Of course, with those, I have to estimate output based on Max ratings and whatnot because they do not intend these things to be generators.

here is a motor i am considering:
https://hobbyking.com/en_us/multistar-elite-3508-268kv-high-voltage-endurance-motor.html

this motor is 268 kv which means it should produce 1 V per 268 rpm less some efficiency. 
it has max of 11 A and max 330 W output.

There are a number of these motors in so many sizes and shapes. I can only assume I want a low kv motor to have the most headroom in using rpm to create volts (and they seem to have higher amp limits too).

What I don't quite understand is how the current comes into play. Amperes are resistance based?  These motors are rated for max current, but they list "No Load Current" ...basically just spinning without a prop, I believe. I don't understand how the current is generated by the motor.

And then converting the power. Say I produce 10 V at 1 A ac.  Can I convert this into 5 V at 2 A dc?  (what if its 20 V at 0.5 A) etc. etc.

Can I just feed the AC into an AC/DC charger (phone charger wall-wart) and it will be ok using the less than 120 V feed?

Im a bit confused even after looking at all the circuit diagrams. They are almost all aimed at a battery making power for a bulb but not the other way around.

Comment: You will need the specifications of the turbine to select a suitable generator. If you take a generator with a power of 300 W and the turbine has much less power, the combination will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether a BLDC motor is used as a motor, or as a generator, the shaft speed is related to voltage, shaft torque is related to current, and mechanical power to electrical power.

If you spin the shaft of a BLDC motor and follow it with a full bridge 3 phase rectifier (6 diodes), you will get a DC voltage source, voltage proportional to spin speed of the motor, from which you can draw a current with your load. As you draw more current, the BLDC will throw more braking torque onto your turbine. The load determines how much current is drawn.

If you're driving a load directly, it's most efficient (electrically) to use a DC to DC converter to get to the constant low voltage you want. If charging batteries, then get a battery charger that runs from a low DC voltage. Using an inverter up to mains voltage, then running mains input chargers will work, and while less efficient than staying with LV DC, may well be more flexible.

There are lots of modules available on eBay that step DC up or down, to adjustable voltages from a wide range of voltages, look for 'DC-DC converter'. These will often be 80-90% efficient, so able to supply 5v at 2A while drawing no more than 1.25A, and maybe as little as 1.1A from a 10v supply.

My major concern is the speed of the two devices. The turbine claims to run up to 20krpm, and I would expect it to provide reasonable power and efficiency only at the upper end of its speed range. While the motor does not appear to have a max speed spec, its kv*max_volts is only 9380rpm. Direct coupling at even 9k rpm could be quite exciting unless you are a skilled model engineer. There are at least 4 reasons you don't want to run the motor too fast, bursting, balance, air losses, and electrical efficiency. A toothed belt reduction drive from one to the other would provide both gearing down and mechanical isolation. An outrunner motor tends to be higher torque and lower speed than the equivalent inrunner, there might be higher speed motors you can choose if you do want to drive directly.

How much electrical power do you want to provide? You have chosen a 330W rated motor. While it's a good idea to have a motor rating several times higher than the power you want to draw, 10x higher is probably overkill, though that will give you plenty of capacity in hand if you want to draw more power later.

Comment: for steam I will be *trying* a pressure cooker at 15psi. Perhaps I should find the DC to DC converter I would use and design everything back from that. 

am I correct in assuming that a motor like I listed will produce less torque per amp due to its high max power?

Comment: thankyou, for your information btw!

Comment: I mentioned the 15psi because I wont be making the full 20krpm that the turbine is capable of. The maker of the turbine uses 30psi in his videos. I do not know if this is max. I doubt it. 
This part of the project is very up in the air (or steam) until I get my hands on it and test. Im trying to make best guesses with a motor that would be....flexible.

Comment: amps per torque varies exactly the same way as rpm per volt, which is is kv, or torque per amp goes as 1/kv. I'd leave the DC to DC converter till you have the turbine and generator running, for me the mechanical bits sound more iffy, but that's just me. Once you have the turbine hooked up to a generator, it's easy to run it under a test load of light bulbs or similar, without having to have the full electrical conversion system going. Half the inlet pressure will give you much less than half the power, IIRC it goes as the cube, so 1/8th of the 30psi power.